# Java Delete files older than N days

Tags: java, file, file-management

I would like some Java code to Delete files older than N days.

Here is my attempt, but it doesn't work quite right.

```
public void deleteFilesOlderThanNdays(final int daysBack, final String dirWay) {

    System.out.println(dirWay);
    System.out.println(daysBack);

    final File directory = new File(dirWay);
    if(directory.exists()){
        System.out.println(" Directory Exists");
        final File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();          
        final long purgeTime = 
            System.currentTimeMillis() - (daysBack * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        System.out.println("System.currentTimeMillis " + 
            System.currentTimeMillis());

        System.out.println("purgeTime " + purgeTime);

        for(File listFile : listFiles) {
            System.out.println("Length : "+ listFiles.length);
            System.out.println("listFile.getName() : " +listFile.getName());
            System.out.println("listFile.lastModified() :"+
                listFile.lastModified());

            if(listFile.lastModified() < purgeTime) {
                System.out.println("Inside File Delete");
            }
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
    }
}
```

Is there some simple code to delete files older than N days in a directory?

Comment: First what are the dates of the files in the directory? Are all the files older than 30 days? Also does `System.out.println("Inside File Delete");` get printed out? More information is needed as it will depend on what arguments you are passing to the method. I don't see a problem with the actual logic of the method which leads me to believe its a problem with the arguments you are passing it, specifically `final int daysBack`

Comment: Do you have to use java? UNIX could do this in one line

Comment: It would help to know what time values you're seeing for the files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042855/delete-files-older-than-x-days

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use the [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)-Class instead:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
 cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, daysBack * -1);  
 long purgeTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Or try [this solution](http://www.coderanch.com/t/538161/java/java/Couldn-delete-all-files-older):

Is your number of days over `24`? If so, you have an overflow problem.

If the number of days is `25`, the value will be:

```
25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

The mathematical value is `2160000000`. However, this is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and therefore the value overflows to
`-12516353`. As a result, the purge time will be in the future, and will never be met. Values larger than `25` will only make the problem worse; it's even possible the overflow is so bad that the multiplication results in a positive value again leading to perhaps purge all files.

The fix is easy:

1. declare `daysBack` as a `long`
2. cast `daysBack` to a `long`

   ```
   long purgeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - ((long)daysBack * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
   ```
3. Use explicit long literals inside the calculation:

   ```
   long purgeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (daysBack * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L);
   ```

For all three solutions, the fact that the first and/or second operand is a long turns the entire result into a long, allowing a value of `2160000000` without overflowing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim for your valudable suggestion It worked and you rock Thanks agai n

Answer (score 8):

I use this simple code snippet to delete files older than N days

In this snippet deletion is based on file last-modified datetime

daysBack = Delete files older than N days
dirWay   = Directory that contain files

```
public static void deleteFilesOlderThanNdays(int daysBack, String dirWay) {

File directory = new File(dirWay);
if(directory.exists()){

    File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();           
    long purgeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (daysBack * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    for(File listFile : listFiles) {
        if(listFile.lastModified() < purgeTime) {
            if(!listFile.delete()) {
                System.err.println("Unable to delete file: " + listFile);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Watch out for int overflow: daysback should be cast to long or declared as a long or the constant should be long:
* 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L

Answer (score 2):

### Java program to delete files in a directory older than N days:

I am not responsible for you accidentally erasing your hard drive computer with this.  Don't run it unless you understand what it does and why it does it.  If you accidentally run this file against root, or some sensitive directory, old files will be permanently erased.

This Java program will gather a list of all the files in  `C:\Users\penguins` that contain the text: `MyLogFile_` in its name.  It looks at the `lastModified()` date of each file, and sees how old it is in milliseconds, if the difference is greater than the number of days specified (8 days in milliseconds), then the file is deleted.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

class Runner{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        long numDays = 8;   //this needs to be a long.

        //WARNING!  OLD FILES IN THIS DIRECTORY WILL BE DELETED.
        String dir = "C:\\Users\\penguins";
        //IF YOU ACCIDENTALLY POINT THIS TO C:\\Windows or other sensitive
        //directory (and run it) you will be living in the house of pain.

        File directory = new File(dir);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

        if (fList != null){
            for (File file : fList){
                if (file.isFile() &&
                    file.getName().contains("MyLogFile_")){

                    long diff = new Date().getTime() - file.lastModified();
                    long cutoff = (numDays * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                    if (diff > cutoff) {
                      file.delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**To get this code to work for you, you need to:**

1. Set the dir to the directory you want to delete files from.
2. set the numDays variable to the number of days past which files get deleted.
3. Set the `MyLogFile_` word to the signature of files you want to delete.  Set it to blank to look at all files.

**When this code will fail you:**

If the system Date is changed to future or past, (or some weird leap-second, timezone change, or system date edit) happens, then this may go on a deleting rampage. If dates on the files are artificially manipulated, then this may go on a deleting rampage.  If permissions are too restrictive on the files, the file won't be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file.lastModified() method

Some thing like below.

File file = new File("YOUR_FOLDER_PATH");

```
long diff = new Date().getTime() - file.lastModified();

 if (diff > Z * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
  file.delete();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "approximately 30 days ago", the other answers are correct. But if you mean to be more precise, then you should pay attention to time zone. And if you mean whole days, pay attention to time-of-day.

If you want to use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT, use this time zone object: `DateTimeZone.UTC`

Here is some example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 3.2 library.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Oslo" );

DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime cutoff = now.minusDays( 30 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();

DateTime fileCreationDateTime = new DateTime( 2014, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, timeZone );
boolean fileShouldBeDeleted = fileCreationDateTime.isBefore( cutoff );

DateTime file2CreationDateTime = now.minusMinutes( 1 );
boolean file2ShouldBeDeleted = file2CreationDateTime.isBefore( cutoff );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "cutoff: " + cutoff );
System.out.println( "fileCreationDateTime: " + fileCreationDateTime );
System.out.println( "fileShouldBeDeleted: " + fileShouldBeDeleted );
System.out.println( "file2CreationDateTime: " + file2CreationDateTime );
System.out.println( "file2ShouldBeDeleted: " + file2ShouldBeDeleted );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-02-07T07:20:32.898+01:00
cutoff: 2014-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00
fileCreationDateTime: 2014-01-02T03:04:05.000+01:00
fileShouldBeDeleted: true
file2CreationDateTime: 2014-02-07T07:19:32.898+01:00
file2ShouldBeDeleted: false
```

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet using Java 8

```
    public static void deleteFilesOlderThanNdays(int daysAgo, String destDir) throws IOException {

    Instant instantDaysAgo = Instant.from(ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(daysAgo));

    BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> fileIsOlderThanNDays = 
            (path, attr) ->  attr.lastModifiedTime().compareTo( FileTime.from(instantDaysAgo)) < 0 ;


    List<Path> filesToDelete = (List) Files.find(Paths.get(destDir), 1 , fileIsOlderThanNDays )
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());


    for (Path path : filesToDelete) {
            Files.delete(path);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was researching something similar and I've wrapped some java.nio.file.Files methods in order to have a clean Java 8 stream based method.

My need was for 7 days period but you can adapt it to your need:

```
public void cleanFilesOlderThan7Days() {
    try {
        Files.walk(Paths.get("temp/raw_reports"))
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .filter(FilesUtils::isOlderThan7Days)
                .forEach(FilesUtils::delete);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Could not clean old files", e);
    }
}
```

I put the wrapped methods in an utils class:

public class FilesUtils {

```
@SneakyThrows
public static boolean isOlderThan7Days(java.nio.file.Path path) {
    FileTime lastModifiedTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path);
    Duration interval = Duration.between(lastModifiedTime.toInstant(), Instant.now());
    return interval.toDays() > 7;
}

@SneakyThrows
public static void delete(java.nio.file.Path path) {
    Files.delete(path);
}
```

}

Notice I am using @SneakyThrows from Lombok plugin. If you are not using it you can either implement it or use try/catch to threat the exceptions.