# Delete files older than x days

Tags: java, time, delete-file

How can I find out when a file was created using java, as I wish to delete files older than a certain time period, currently I am deleting all files in a directory, but this is not ideal:

```
public void DeleteFiles() {
    File file = new File("D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/");
    System.out.println("Called deleteFiles");
    DeleteFiles(file);
    File file2 = new File("D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/");
    DeleteFilesNonPdf(file2);
}

public void DeleteFiles(File file) {
    System.out.println("Now will search folders and delete files,");
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
            DeleteFiles(f);
        }
    } else {
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

Above is my current code, I am trying now to add an if statement in that will only delete files older than say a week.

EDIT:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class Delete {

    public void DeleteFiles() {
        File file = new File("D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/");
        System.out.println("Called deleteFiles");
        DeleteFiles(file);
        File file2 = new File("D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/");
        DeleteFilesNonPdf(file2);
    }

    public void DeleteFiles(File file) {
        System.out.println("Now will search folders and delete files,");
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Date Modified : " + file.lastModified());
            for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                DeleteFiles(f);
            }
        } else {
            file.delete();
        }
    }
```

Adding a loop now.

EDIT

I have noticed while testing the code above I get the last modified in :

```
INFO: Date Modified : 1361635382096
```

How should I code the if loop to say if it is older than 7 days delete it when it is in the above format?

Answer (score 50):

You can use [`File.lastModified()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) to get the last modified time of a file/directory.

Can be used like this:

```
long diff = new Date().getTime() - file.lastModified();

if (diff > x * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
    file.delete();
}
```

Which deletes files older than `x` (an `int`) days.

Comment: it will give the last modified time not the file creation time.

Comment: Thats fine, no modificatins can be done to the file once it is created no one can edit it :)

Comment: :D That's really simple. i'm writing the ans for file creation time. ;)

Comment: Thanks ! :) am testing it atm but so far looks perfect !

Comment: With X == 25 you get int overflow. 25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L is more robust

Answer (score 33):

[Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) has built-in support for filtering files by age with its [AgeFileFilter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter.html). Your `DeleteFiles` could just look like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.AgeFileFilter;
import static org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter.TRUE;

// a Date defined somewhere for the cutoff date
Date thresholdDate = <the oldest age you want to keep>;

public void DeleteFiles(File file) {
    Iterator<File> filesToDelete =
        FileUtils.iterateFiles(file, new AgeFileFilter(thresholdDate), TRUE);
    for (File aFile : filesToDelete) {
        aFile.delete();
    }
}
```

**Update:** To use the value as given in your edit, define the `thresholdDate` as:

```
Date tresholdDate = new Date(1361635382096L);
```

Comment: Is there any way you can combine the AgeFileFilter with another filter, such as the NameFileFilter?

Comment: @NathanChristie see [AndFileFilter](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AndFileFilter.html) and [OrFileFilter](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/OrFileFilter.html)

Comment: Parameters: iterateFiles(File directory, IOFileFilter fileFilter,                IOFileFilter dirFilter), dirfilter is optional (can be null)

Comment: Example does not compile, cannot iterate over `Iterator` Probably want to use listFiles?

Answer (score 17):

Using Apache utils is probably the easiest. Here is the simplest solution I could come up with.

```
public void deleteOldFiles() {
    Date oldestAllowedFileDate = DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -3); //minus days from current date
    File targetDir = new File("C:\\TEMP\\archive\\");
    Iterator<File> filesToDelete = FileUtils.iterateFiles(targetDir, new AgeFileFilter(oldestAllowedFileDate), null);
    //if deleting subdirs, replace null above with TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE
    while (filesToDelete.hasNext()) {
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(filesToDelete.next());
    }  //I don't want an exception if a file is not deleted. Otherwise use filesToDelete.next().delete() in a try/catch
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can use milliseconds to create an AgeFileFilter like this `new AgeFileFilter(System.currentTimeMillis() - AGE_LIMIT_MILLIS)` where AGE_LIMIT_MILLIS could be say 24*60*60*1000L for 24 hours.

Comment: @MattC Does this have any impact like out of memory exception if i use it for the directory having 2 or 3 million records?

Comment: @Diwa Yes, I am guessing you could run into memory issues if you had millions of files. FileUtils creates a java.util.LinkedList, and then returns the iterator of that list.

Answer (score 14):

## Example using Java 8's Time API

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate eailer = today.minusDays(30);
    
Date threshold = Date.from(eailer.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
AgeFileFilter filter = new AgeFileFilter(threshold);
    
File path = new File("...");
File[] oldFolders = FileFilterUtils.filter(filter, path);
    
for (File folder : oldFolders) {
    System.out.println(folder);
}
```

Comment: To be clear, AgeFileFilter is from Apache Commons IO, not from the Java 8 Time API.

Answer (score 13):

Here's Java 8 version using Time API. It's been tested and used in our project:

```
    public static int deleteFiles(final Path destination,
        final Integer daysToKeep) throws IOException {

    final Instant retentionFilePeriod = ZonedDateTime.now()
            .minusDays(daysToKeep).toInstant();

    final AtomicInteger countDeletedFiles = new AtomicInteger();
    Files.find(destination, 1,
            (path, basicFileAttrs) -> basicFileAttrs.lastModifiedTime()
                    .toInstant().isBefore(retentionFilePeriod))
            .forEach(fileToDelete -> {
                try {
                    if (!Files.isDirectory(fileToDelete)) {
                        Files.delete(fileToDelete);
                        countDeletedFiles.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            });

    return countDeletedFiles.get();
}
```

Comment: I was adapting this for what I needed, and had a warning from SonarQube noting that the Files.find stream should be closed, or ideally put into a try with resources block.

Answer (score 12):

## Using lambdas (Java 8+)

**Non recursive option to delete all files in current folder that are older than N days (ignores sub folders):**

```
public static void deleteFilesOlderThanNDays(int days, String dirPath) throws IOException {
    long cutOff = System.currentTimeMillis() - (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    Files.list(Paths.get(dirPath))
    .filter(path -> {
        try {
            return Files.isRegularFile(path) && Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) < cutOff;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // log here and move on
            return false;
        }
    })
    .forEach(path -> {
        try {
            Files.delete(path);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // log here and move on
        }
    });
}
```

**Recursive option, that traverses sub-folders and deletes all files that are older than N days:**

```
public static void recursiveDeleteFilesOlderThanNDays(int days, String dirPath) throws IOException {
    long cutOff = System.currentTimeMillis() - (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    Files.list(Paths.get(dirPath))
    .forEach(path -> {
        if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
            try {
                recursiveDeleteFilesOlderThanNDays(days, path.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // log here and move on
            }
        } else {
            try {
                if (Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) < cutOff) {
                    Files.delete(path);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // log here and move on
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For a JDK 8 solution using both NIO file streams and JSR-310

```
long cut = LocalDateTime.now().minusWeeks(1).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/delete");
Files.list(path)
        .filter(n -> {
            try {
                return Files.getLastModifiedTime(n)
                        .to(TimeUnit.SECONDS) < cut;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //handle exception
                return false;
            }
        })
        .forEach(n -> {
            try {
                Files.delete(n);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //handle exception
            }
        });
```

The sucky thing here is the need for handling exceptions within each lambda. It would have been great for the API to have `UncheckedIOException` overloads for each IO method. With helpers to do this one could write:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    long cut = LocalDateTime.now().minusWeeks(1).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/delete");
    Files.list(path)
            .filter(n -> Files2.getLastModifiedTimeUnchecked(n)
                    .to(TimeUnit.SECONDS) < cut)
            .forEach(n -> {
                System.out.println(n);
                Files2.delete(n, (t, u)
                              -> System.err.format("Couldn't delete %s%n",
                                                   t, u.getMessage())
                );
            });
}


private static final class Files2 {

    public static FileTime getLastModifiedTimeUnchecked(Path path,
            LinkOption... options)
            throws UncheckedIOException {
        try {
            return Files.getLastModifiedTime(path, options);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void delete(Path path, BiConsumer<Path, Exception> e) {
        try {
            Files.delete(path);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            e.accept(path, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

JavaSE Canonical Solution.
Delete files older than `expirationPeriod` days.

```
private void cleanUpOldFiles(String folderPath, int expirationPeriod) {
    File targetDir = new File(folderPath);
    if (!targetDir.exists()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Log files directory '%s' " +
                "does not exist in the environment", folderPath));
    }

    File[] files = targetDir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        long diff = new Date().getTime() - file.lastModified();

        // Granularity = DAYS;
        long desiredLifespan = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(expirationPeriod); 

        if (diff > desiredLifespan) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

e.g. - to removed all files older than 30 days in folder "/sftp/logs" call:

`cleanUpOldFiles("/sftp/logs", 30);`

Answer (score 4):

You can get the creation date of the file using NIO, following is the way:

```
BasicFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
System.out.println("creationTime: " + attrs.creationTime());
```

More about it can be found here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html

Comment: `BasicFileAttributes` is available only with java 7. You can not use it with java 6 or earlier releases.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach with Apache commons-io and joda:

```
private void deleteOldFiles(String dir, int daysToRemainFiles) {
    Collection<File> filesToDelete = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(dir),
            new AgeFileFilter(DateTime.now().withTimeAtStartOfDay().minusDays(daysToRemainFiles).toDate()),
            TrueFileFilter.TRUE);    // include sub dirs
    for (File file : filesToDelete) {
        boolean success = FileUtils.deleteQuietly(file);
        if (!success) {
            // log...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Using Java NIO Files with lambdas & Commons IO

```
final long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Only show files & directories older than 2 days
final long maxdiff = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(2);
```

List all found files and directories:

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("."), p -> (time - p.toFile().lastModified()) < maxdiff)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or delete found files with [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html):

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("."), p -> (time - p.toFile().lastModified()) < maxdiff)
.forEach(p -> FileUtils.deleteQuietly(p.toFile()));
```

Comment: Would suggest using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, also I think it should be `>` .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to delete files which are not modified since six months & also create the log file.

```
package deleteFiles;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class Delete {
    public static void deleteFiles()
    {
        int numOfMonths = -6;
        String path="G:\\Files";
        File file = new File(path);
        FileHandler fh;
        Calendar sixMonthAgo = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
        sixMonthAgo.add(Calendar.MONTH, numOfMonths);
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            fh = new FileHandler("G:\\Files\\logFile\\MyLogForDeletedFile.log");
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);

            for (File f:files)
            {
                if (f.isFile() && f.exists())
                {
                    Date lastModDate = new Date(f.lastModified());
                    if(lastModDate.before(sixMonthAgo.getTime()))
                    {
                        arrlist.add(f.getName());
                        f.delete();
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<arrlist.size();i++)
                logger.info("deleted files are ===>"+arrlist.get(i));
        }
        catch ( Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.info("error is-->"+e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        deleteFiles();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more helpful to explain the parts that the OP doesn't understand, rather than providing them with a bulk of code that does approximately what they wanted. Take a look at the accepted answer here, it has much less code than yours, but more explanation and it solved the question succinctly.

Answer (score 0):

Need to point out a bug on the first solution listed, x * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 will max out int value if x is big. So need to cast it to long value

```
long diff = new Date().getTime() - file.lastModified();

if (diff > (long) x * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
    file.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this Java 11 & Spring solution will be useful to someone:

```
private void removeOldBackupFolders(Path folder, String name) throws IOException {
    var current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    var difference = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(7);

    BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> predicate =
        (path, attributes) ->
            path.getFileName().toString().contains(name)
                && (current - attributes.lastModifiedTime().toMillis()) > difference;

    try (var stream = Files.find(folder, 1, predicate)) {
      stream.forEach(
          path -> {
            try {
              FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(path);

              log.warn("Deleted old backup {}", path.getFileName());
            } catch (IOException lambdaEx) {
              log.error("", lambdaEx);
            }
          });
    }
}
```

The `BiPredicate` is used to filter files (i.e. files & folder in Java) by `name` and `age`.

`FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively()` is a Spring method that recursively removes files & folders. You can change that to something like NIO.2 `Files.files.walkFileTree()` if you don't want to use Spring dependencies.

I've set the `maxDepth` of `Files.find()` to 1 based on my use case. You can set to it unlimited `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and risk irreversibly deleting your dev FS if you are not careful.

Example logs based on `var difference = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(3)`:

```
2022-05-20 00:54:15.505  WARN 24680 --- [       single-1] u.t.s.service.impl.BackupServiceImpl     : Deleted old backup backup_20052022_1652989557462
2022-05-20 00:54:15.506  WARN 24680 --- [       single-1] u.t.s.service.impl.BackupServiceImpl     : Deleted old backup backup_20052022_1652989558474
2022-05-20 00:54:15.507  WARN 24680 --- [       single-1] u.t.s.service.impl.BackupServiceImpl     : Deleted old backup backup_20052022_1652989589723
2022-05-20 00:54:15.508  WARN 24680 --- [       single-1] u.t.s.service.impl.BackupServiceImpl     : Deleted old backup backup_20052022_1652989674083
```

Notes:

- The stream of `Files.find()` must be wrapped inside of a try-with-resource (utilizing `AutoCloseable`) or handled the old-school way inside of a try-finally to close the stream.
- A good example of `Files.walkFileTree()` for copying (can be adapted for deletion): https://stackoverflow.com/a/60621544/3242022

Answer (score -1):

Using Apache commons-io and joda:

```
        if ( FileUtils.isFileOlder(f, DateTime.now().minusDays(30).toDate()) ) {
            f.delete();
        }
```