# Android - Saving logcat to a file and limit the file size

Tags: android, logcat

I am able to save the logcat to external file with the link - [Saving Logcat to a text file in Android Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565685/saving-logcat-to-a-text-file-in-android-device)

Is there any way to limit the file size? i.e. For e.g. I want the output file size shouldn't exceed 2MB. If it exceeds the limit, it should clear the existing file content and start writing the new content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to set the condition while reading the file

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
File file = new File("text.txt");
long filesize = file.length();
long filesizeInKB = filesize / 1024;
long filesizeinMB=filesizeInKB/1024;
```

Comment: I think part of your answer is missing, please also format only code as such

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing

```
 process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile);
```

Add

```
 process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile + " -r <kbytes> -n <count>");
```

Example for a maximum of 10 files, where each max size is 500kb :

```
 process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile + " -r 500 -n 10");
```

You can also defined theses variables (*500* and *10*) in your environment variables to keep your code maintainable.

Source : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat